# Call Auth::user()->id triggered an error in conditional instruction

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a simple problem. For example sometimes I need to call `Auth::user()->id` in conditional but if I'm not logged in, it triggers an error. For example
`@if(isset(Auth::user()->id)) //do something @endif`
How can I do that in a simple way to make it work?

I want to make only one conditional instruction that works

Comment: You can use the `@auth` blade directive if you are in the blade component to check if user is authenticated, and then get Id or relationships within the scope of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `id()` directly, it will return either `null` or the id of the user

```
@if(Auth::id())
```

Or use `check()`, it will return `true` or `false` and is equivalent for `! is_null(Auth::user())`

```
@if(Auth::check())
```

Comment: OK. Propably it will be works but sometimes I need to call User's relationship - `Auth::user()->profile->age` and it doesn't solve my problem. For example sometimes I need check that user set his age and in this method I need to create 2 conditionals.

Comment: if some views/pages need a user to be shown then block it upstream with a middleware. if not you can do both in the same condition `@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->profile->age > 18)` it will not trigger an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Auth::check()` for the condition. If you are using guard other than `web` authentication guard then write like this `Auth::guard('guard_name')->check()`.